# Displaying SELECT tag larger in mobile browser

Tags: html, iphone, select, mobile

I'm trying to design a mobile version of a website and the SELECT tag is displaying very tiny on the iPhone. Please see attached screenshot. I'm trying to design it closer to specs that client layed out in a photoshop file. Please see screenshot of how client would like it to appear. Any suggestions on how to make this happen? I've tried to use CSS to size width and height to no avail.

This is for a mobile website and not a native app.

iPhone preview:
[image: iphone preview]

Client mockup:
[image: client mockup]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much you can do to standard HTML select tag. I think you can achieve this by using some java script based UI components. Have a look at one of jQuery plugin called [Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)